# how to add .exe dependency so that I have a single Runnable JAR File

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jar

I have written Selenium Webdriver Java (in Eclipse) automation test Script which I run in Chrome Browser.
The script depends on a chromedriver.exe which I have added in my project dependency folder.

I am able to add the dependent .jar files in runnable jar but not .exe files.
Is there a way where I able to export a single runnable jar which also includes the chromedriver.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

I have separate running jar , which using chromedriver.exe
just hardcoded regular configuration

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
```

so, driver must be near .jar and this works. Fast and dirty, yes.

Not sure, if you could export jar with dependent exe.

Comment: Currently I am using this way only.